# How do you return JSON data using an AJAX asynchronous call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I created a form that posts data via Ajax. I would like to get the results/return value of my Ajax call within a submitHandler:

My code is below:

```
      submitHandler: function(form) {



             $.ajax({

                url: '/checkaddress',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('form#proteinForm').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.delivery_line_1);

                }

              });


      }
```

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to see if it succeeds and if the response body is valid json.

Comment: Also get in habit of using error handlers for such requests

Comment: @charlietfl Do you have an example of an error handler?

Comment: Sure...in the `$.ajax` documents

Comment: @charlietfl My mistake. I misread your comment. I added an error handler and a breakpoint. I am returned a 200 message so my request succeeded. My question is that I would like to get the results/return value of my Ajax call

Comment: well what does `data` look like? You need to consume it in the ajax success handler

Comment: @charlietfl  Data is empty. It should send me a result after I submit the data

Comment: If request succeeds but data is empty sounds like something wrong server side then.

Comment: @charlietfl I will check on the server side. Thanks